# Sphinx :ivar tag goes looking for cross-references

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to document Python object attributes with Sphinx. I understand I should use

```
:ivar varname: description
:ivar type varname: description
```

However I'm seeing a weird behaviour, that is Sphinx searches my project for the variable name and tries to create symlinks.
E.g. this code:

```
class A(object):
    """
    :ivar x: some description
    """
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class B(object):
    def x(self):
        return 1

class C(object):
    def x(self):
        return 2
```

will cause this error:

> module1.py:docstring of mylibrary.module1.A:None: WARNING: more than one target found for cross-reference u'x': mylibrary.module1.C.x, mylibrary.module1.B.x

Did I understand incorrectly the purpose or usage of :ivar?

Comment: So if you remove `:ivar x: some description`, the error goes away?

Comment: Yes, the error is caused by :ivar and if I delete class C then I get no error, but in html I get an unwanted symlink from A.x to B.x

Comment: I have the same problem.  It does not happen for all :ivar, only in cases where the name of the instance variable is used by other classes/modules.  The concerning thing is that :ivar should not (to my understanding) be creating a cross-reference at all

Comment: Reported as a bug here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2549

Answer (score 5):

Here is a monkey patch (based on Sphinx 1.5.1) that disables `ivar` cross-references. I'm not sure what the best solution is, so consider the patch an experimental suggestion. To try it out, add the code below to `conf.py`.

```
from docutils import nodes
from sphinx.util.docfields import TypedField
from sphinx import addnodes

def patched_make_field(self, types, domain, items):
    # type: (List, unicode, Tuple) -> nodes.field
    def handle_item(fieldarg, content):
        par = nodes.paragraph()
        par += addnodes.literal_strong('', fieldarg)  # Patch: this line added
        #par.extend(self.make_xrefs(self.rolename, domain, fieldarg,
        #                           addnodes.literal_strong))
        if fieldarg in types:
            par += nodes.Text(' (')
            # NOTE: using .pop() here to prevent a single type node to be
            # inserted twice into the doctree, which leads to
            # inconsistencies later when references are resolved
            fieldtype = types.pop(fieldarg)
            if len(fieldtype) == 1 and isinstance(fieldtype[0], nodes.Text):
                typename = u''.join(n.astext() for n in fieldtype)
                par.extend(self.make_xrefs(self.typerolename, domain, typename,
                                           addnodes.literal_emphasis))
            else:
                par += fieldtype
            par += nodes.Text(')')
        par += nodes.Text(' -- ')
        par += content
        return par

    fieldname = nodes.field_name('', self.label)
    if len(items) == 1 and self.can_collapse:
        fieldarg, content = items[0]
        bodynode = handle_item(fieldarg, content)
    else:
        bodynode = self.list_type()
        for fieldarg, content in items:
            bodynode += nodes.list_item('', handle_item(fieldarg, content))
    fieldbody = nodes.field_body('', bodynode)
    return nodes.field('', fieldname, fieldbody)

TypedField.make_field = patched_make_field
```

The original `TypedField.make_field` method is here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/util/docfields.py.

Comment: This does work!  It feels a bit hacky of course and I don't know if it works on RTD yet, but granting the bounty because it satisfies the parameters of the request (and hopefully someone will actually fix the sphinx ticket at some point, but this will work in the meantime).

Comment: At least the actual change is small; one line of code substituted for another. The patch can be applied to earlier versions of Sphinx too, btw.

Comment: Works. It complained for the argument mismatch though. Just pass on another optional argument to it as `patched_make_field(self, types, domain, items, env=None)`.

Comment: @SauravSahu: Yes, monkey patches can be fragile. docfields.py has had several changes after I posted the answer. The related bug report is still open: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2549.

Comment: Apparently broken with Sphinx 3.4.0: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2549#issuecomment-754005957

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround provided by `@acrisci` on github: prefix your variable name with `~.`. For example replace

```
:ivar float bandwidth: blah
```

with this:

```
:ivar float ~.bandwidth: blah
```

Source: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2549#issuecomment-488896939

Comment: Doesn't work: ``WARNING: py:obj reference target not found: .bandwidth``

Answer (score 1):

As **mzjn** referred there is an [open issue for this SO post](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2549). In that thread there is also already a work-around for the issue posted. In sum, you use inline comments `#:` instead of the docstring.

Take a look at the `python.py` file in the commit referred by the user [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/1848/files#r75794956). The docstring entries were removed (red lines), and he added inline comments in the constructor (green lines).

I have been looking for documentation on this but could not find it.
For instance:

```
(...)
def __init__(self, function, fixtureinfo, config, cls=None, module=None):
    #: access to the :class:`_pytest.config.Config` object for the test session
    self.config = config
    (...)
```

As noted by **Nick Bastin**  this work-around renders completely differently from `:ivar:`. There is no type support, and it always renders the default value.

Comment: The problem is that `#:` renders completely differently from `:ivar:` (and its' ilk).  There is no type support, it always renders the default value, and is not as compact.

Comment: I feel you, it is not a solution, just a workaround.  I just added the info here to complete the thread since the issue originated from here. I will add your notes as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative with other advantages. Just define you member variables at class scope and document them with plain docstring. Later you can reference them with [`py:attr:`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#role-py:attr) role. It's more readable, self-documented (yeah, I know this is under [python-sphinx](/questions/tagged/python-sphinx), but anyway) and introspection-friendly approach.

*module.py*

```
class A:

    x = None
    '''This way there's no issue. It is more readable and friendly
    for class member introspection.'''


    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class B:
    '''Something about :py:attr:`.A.x`'''

    def x(self):
        '''Method x of B'''
        return 1
```

*README.txt*

```
****
Test
****

.. autoclass:: module.A
   :members:

.. autoclass:: module.B
   :members:
```

*conf.py*

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']

source_suffix = '.txt'

master_doc = 'README'

project = 'Test'

pygments_style = 'sphinx'

html_theme = 'alabaster'

html_use_index       = False
html_show_sourcelink = False
html_show_copyright  = False

html_sidebars = {'**': ['localtoc.html']}
```

Build like `PYTHONPATH=. sphinx-build . html`.

Comment: This fundamentally changes the things that can be done with your code - class attributes are completely different from instance attributes.  Also, you can just use `:py:attr:` without doing this, but it's also not rendered in the same way (either as class or instance attributes).

Comment: @NickBastin I don't see any "fundamental changes" to the class that "defines" its members this way. I see only the benefits. Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: The simplest example is that your change allows `A.x` to have a value, while in the proper code, only `A().x` has a value (and trying to access `A.x` will give you an exception).  This can easily cause subtle bugs, or worse.  Regardless, documentation shouldn't require the behaviour of actual code to be changed.

Comment: @NickBastin In my example, even though I want to talk about higher level abstraction of class members, class attributes have gotten `None` value. Object attributes in initialiser rebind them. I cannot imagine a way for a well-written code to break because of this. Either it is an already broken code that erroneously passes a classes instead of its instance somewhere. Or it is a poorly-written code that makes a decision basing on present of attribute (in `__dict__`), not its value. So again I see your opinion as unfounded...

Comment: @NickBastin ...well, except that one obviously does not need to rewrite their classes just because `var` doesn't work in Sphinx properly. In sense of the question it's a workaround. But personally I always write classes this way and have never encountered an issue with it. You can also see this pattern in some known packages like cherrypy, sqlalchemy (and likely others). It's a way write a class per se. A way to declare all members in class scope (first indentation level of class) so it's easier to reason about its state and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is finally fixed in **Sphinx 4.0.0.beta1** released on 2021-04-12.

The next stable release of Sphinx that contains it will be 4.0 or 4.1.

(Issue: [#5977](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5977) , PR that fixed it: [#8638](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/8638), changelog entry for 4.0 beta 1: [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/4.x/CHANGES#L81-L82))

Answer (score 0):

For those running older Sphinx versions than 4.0, here is a much simpler fix than the monkey-patch from @mzjn that was tested back to Sphinx 1.6.7 from Ubuntu 18.04. The fix basically just does the same thing that was done in PR [#8638](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/8638) that fixed the issue.

Put the following code into your conf.py:

```
from sphinx.domains.python import PyObject
PyObject.doc_field_types[map(lambda f: f.name == 'variable', PyObject.doc_field_types).index(True)].rolename = None
```