# Some way to disable ivar auto-cross-referencing of attribute names

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

When using Napoleon with google docstrings (I haven't tested numpy, but I suspect similar problems) with the `napoleon_use_ivar` option set to `True`, it creates links to the *names* of instance variables.  These names are obviously very common (things like "name"), and linking them to some random definition is not helpful - is there any way to disable this?

Given the following docstring:

```
"""
Attributes:
  name (str): Friendly name
"""
```

It will attempt to cross-reference `name` in the html output.  It complains about this, given the ambiguity of the target:

```
/home/nbastin/geni-lib/geni/rspec/pgad.py:docstring of geni.rspec.pgad.AdInterface:None: WARNING: more than one target found for cross-reference u'name': geni.rspec.igext.AddressPool.name, geni.rspec.vtsmanifest.GREPort.name, geni.rspec.vtsmanifest.InternalPort.name, geni.rspec.pg.
Node.name, geni.rspec.vtsmanifest.PGLocalPort.name, geni.rspec.pg.Interface.name, geni.rspec.vtsmanifest.GenericPort.name, geni.rspec.vtsmanifest.ManifestContainer.name, geni.urn.GENI.name, geni.rspec.vtsmanifest.InternalContainerPort.name
```

However, it still creates a link in the HTML output - if you click on the `name` attribute it happily sends you to some random symbol that has nothing to do with the current attribute.  Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

If `napoleon_use_ivar` is set to `False` this doesn't happen, but the attribute output is not at all compact and is very hard to read.

This is *not* Napoleon specific - if you specify the attributes by hand with `ivar` it also cross-references them in a way you cannot control:

```
:ivar name: Friendly name
:vartype name: str
```

That still gets a link for `name`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sphinx :ivar tag goes looking for cross-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784830/sphinx-ivar-tag-goes-looking-for-cross-references)